# Is there an 'output' option in the youtube_dL module?

Tags: python, youtube-dl

Say I have a script such as follows

```
import youtube_dl

ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(
    {'format':'best',
    'output':'C:/Users/my_profile/Desktop/%(title)s.%(ext)s'}
)
ydl.download(['Any Link'])
```

Here the output option isn't working. I wonder if there is such an option! Even if it isn't `output` what should I use so that I can have the desired results by using somewhat similar code?

Comment: first check documentation to see if option `output` exists (instead of asking us). You should also check option for `download()` because maybe it can get name for output file - but this will need to create filename manually.

Comment: what means `"isn't working"`? Do you get error message? You should show full message in question - we can't read in your mind and you have to put all details in questions.

Comment: It actually just downloaded the video for the given link on the same folder where I had the sample code. The line `'output' : 'path/to/the/folder/%(title)s.%(ext)s'` didn't actually do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging in source code I found command line option `-o`, `--output` in file [options.py](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/options.py#L688) and it shows that it assigns it to `dest="outtmpl"`

If I use this `outtmpl` in code then it works

```py
import youtube_dl

ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({
    'format': 'best',
    'outtmpl': '~/Desktop/%(title)s.%(ext)s'
})

ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KqmGZ_6LaUw'])
```

And I get file `~/Desktop/Kraftwerk - Neon Lights.mp4`

---

Because I tested it on Linux so I could use `~` instead of `C:/Users/my_profile` but I don't know if it works on Windows.

Comment: I have also tried with `'outtmpl'` but it isn't doing anything. It is just downloading the video where I have kept the sample code.

Comment: did you try with your path `'C:/Users/my_profile/Desktop/%(title)s.%(ext)s'` ? Do you have folder `C:/Users/my_profile/Desktop` ? OR maybe you should use `'C:\\Users\\my_profile\\Desktop\\%(title)s.%(ext)s'` in WIndows

Comment: Yes I tried with `'C:/Users/my_profile/Desktop/%(title)s.%(ext)s'` and `'C:\\Users\\my_profile\\Desktop\\%(title)s.%(ext)s'` but neither of them are working and the file is getting downloaded on the folder where the sample code is present.

Comment: it works on Linux and I don't use Windows to check why it not work. I can't help more. You could first check if this path  works in command line - `youtube-dl -o your_path ...`. You could also add `print()` in code to check if you really run code with `outtmpl` - maybe you changed in one file but you run different file.

Comment: When I ran `youtube-dl -o "C:/Users/my_profile/Desktop/Youtube Videos/%(title)s.%(ext)s" link` it works with no issue but the same doesn't work with the `outtmpl`, thank you for this help and I will try different methods to find why this isn't working.

Comment: I ran the code again and it seems it's working fine and I am guessing I had made a silly error, where I have written `'outtmpl:'` instead of `'outtmpl'` (I think maybe that was the issue).